# {merged} or {closed} markers for merged questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, merged-questions

<sup>I had to use `{x}` in the title, because I'm not allowed to use `[x]` (especially not `[closed]`):</sup>

> <sup>Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:</sup>
>
> - <sup>title can't include the closed marker.</sup>
> - <sup>title contains a [tag] prefix; please use the tag field to enter tags instead.</sup>

---

### Background

AFAICT, merged questions are essentially closed (as duplicate) with their answers moved to another, referenced question.

Different from closed questions, merged questions  don't have a `[closed]` or similar marker in their title, even though nobody can post answers for them either.

### Examples

#### Second topic [here](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx?sort=votes&pagesize=2):

> [image]
>
> [image]

#### [This](https://superuser.com/questions/64516/suggested-lightweight-linux-distribution-to-run-side-by-side-windows) topic:

> [image]

---

### Request

Please add a marker similar to `[closed]` or `[migrated]` to merged questions, e.g. `[merged]`. It could also simply re-use `[closed]`, because their result is very similar from a user's POV.

Comment: has been marked as [tag:status-bydesign] before [Closed-then-merged question missing "closed by" and "merged to" footers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53322)

Comment: Isn't that a completely different issue?

Comment: @Sathya To clarify, this is about identifying these topics in any list of questions using a marker like `[closed]` after the topic title. Since merged questions have a *merged by Username* note, it's pretty obvious what's going on *once you view the topic*.